# why do sqlplus variables act funny with a period?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

why do sqplus variables act funny when attempting to use a period after them?

```
SQL> set define on
SQL> accept goo char prompt 'goo: ';
goo: mygoo
SQL> select '&goo' from dual;
old   1: select '&goo' from dual
new   1: select 'mygoo' from dual

MYGO
-----
mygoo

SQL> select '&goo something' from dual;
old   1: select '&goo something' from dual
new   1: select 'mygoo something' from dual

MYGOOSOMETHING
---------------
mygoo something

SQL> select '&goo.something' from dual;
old   1: select '&goo.something' from dual
new   1: select 'mygoosomething' from dual

MYGOOSOMETHIN
--------------
mygoosomething

SQL> select '&goo..something' from dual;
old   1: select '&goo..something' from dual
new   1: select 'mygoo.something' from dual

MYGOO.SOMETHIN
---------------
mygoo.something
```

why do I have to double up on periods? is there some better way?

Comment: It's probably good practice to always end substitution variables with a `.` to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not *funny* at all, but expected default behavior.

`SET CONCAT` character is a period (unless you set it to some other character). If you want to add a period right after the substitution variable, you have to use two consecutive periods.

If you set concat character to e.g. `#`, then period acts *normally*:

```
SQL> set concat '#'
SQL> select '&goo.' from dual;
old   1: select '&goo.' from dual
new   1: select 'mygoo.' from dual

'MYGOO
------
mygoo.
```

If you set it back to a period, it acts *funny* again:

```
SQL> set concat '.'
SQL> select '&goo.' from dual;
old   1: select '&goo.' from dual
new   1: select 'mygoo' from dual

'MYGO
-----
mygoo

SQL> select '&goo..' from dual;
old   1: select '&goo..' from dual
new   1: select 'mygoo.' from dual

'MYGOO
------
mygoo.
```

Finally, back to `#`, which also acts *funny* and you have to use two of them:

```
SQL> set concat '#'
SQL> select '&goo#' from dual;
old   1: select '&goo#' from dual
new   1: select 'mygoo' from dual

'MYGO
-----
mygoo

SQL> select '&goo##' from dual;
old   1: select '&goo##' from dual
new   1: select 'mygoo#' from dual

'MYGOO
------
mygoo#

SQL>
```